# delete all lines from text except first using ANT

Tags: ant

Is there a way to delete all the text from a text file using ANT except the first line?
Example:

```
First line
Second line
.....
Line n
```

I want to delete everything except first line. The lines can contain any text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`<loadfile>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) with a [`<headfilter>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#headfilter) to get just the first line of a file. Then, the original file can be overwritten using [the `file` attribute of `<echo>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html).

```xml
<!-- Use headfilter to save the file's first line in a property. -->
<loadfile srcfile="${text.file}" property="first.line">
    <filterchain>
        <headfilter lines="1"/>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<!-- Overwrite the file with only the first line. -->
<echo file="${text.file}">${first.line}</echo>
```

### test.txt before running Ant

```
First line
Second line
.....
Line n
```

### test.txt after running Ant

```
First line
```